# Out of stock products and count not displaying in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, navigation

We have 1 out of stock product and 78 in stock products. But in layered navigation I am getting In stock(79) which is wrong.

I have set "Display out of stock product to YES" in admin configuration.

Please check image for more clarification.[image]

Comment: Please check your 1 out of stock product. Is that really out of stock or not?.

Comment: I have checked in admin status is out of stock but on detail page it showing In Stock! How is it possible?

Comment: Can you create a custom code to show Quantity?.

Comment: So there is no way to do it from magento admin?

Comment: Are you using any third party extension for In stock filter? If yes, then check its logic whether it is actually excluding out of stock products while rendering count.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use [Product Stock Indexer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html). Try to do these steps:

1. reindex `cataloginventory_stock`

   run `bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock`  in console
2. flush cache

   run `bin/magento cache:flush`  in console
3. flush varnish cache (additional, if you use one)

   run `sudo service varnish restart` in console

Comment: followed all steps but still same..

Comment: do you use any custom modules that possibly change this default behaviour?

Comment: No we have just created custom theme for design didn't do anything for navigation.